# Can't solve "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" with using GADInterstitial (AdMob) in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I can't solve "Attempt to ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" when I use GADInterstitial in Xcode.

When I move to background from mainViewController and come back to my app, the interstitial appear.
But when I move to background from next ViewController and come back to my app, the interstitial didn't appear and the error occurred.
The way to move to ViewController is modal.

In the same way,
main ViewController -> move to nextViewController -> move to mainViewController -> go to background -> come back to app (mainViewController) -> interstitial didn't appear.

How can I solve this problem?

====================================

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    NSNotification *n = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"inst" object:self];

}
```

**mainViewController** and **bViewController**

(all of code is same except "the target to move of "moveToB")

```
#import "AdMob.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad{
.
.
//if become active, show interstitial
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(showInst) name:@"inst" object:self];    

}

-(void)moveToB{
    bViewController *nextViewController = [[bViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];    
    [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//show interstitial
-(void)showInst{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[AdMob sharedInstance].interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    });
}
```

**AdMob.m**

```
#import "AdMob.h"

@implementation AdMob

static AdMob *sharedData_ = nil;

+ (AdMob *)sharedInstance{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (!sharedData_) {
            sharedData_ = [[AdMob alloc]init];
        }
    }
    return sharedData_;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];

    }
    return self;
}

- (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial { 
    GADInterstitial *interstitial =
    [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:AdMobInsteID];
    interstitial.delegate = self;
    [GADRequest request].testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID, @"myID" ];
    [interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    return interstitial;

}

-(void)loadAdMobInste:(UIViewController*)vc rate:(float)rate{

    if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:vc];
    }

}


- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    NSLog(@"load");
    self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
}


@end
```

Comment: as you are presenting 2nd view and agin while app become active you are presenting ad view so you need to either push or add subview method so it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed modal to push and it did work well. Thank you very much. But why didn't it work even it does "dispatch_after ...some seconds"? I thought if interstitial appears with delay, the 2nd VC will be appear before interstitial, not at the same time.